# how to use Fluent UI HoverCard in SPFX Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

In my current project there's requirement to show more details when hovering on a read more HTML span, where specified functionality is to show Fluent UI HoverCard with all the details, I am trying to read the docs and apply the example given in my solution but in the docs the example looks pretty ambiguous as it only uses a DetailsList control in the example which is not clear if we are looking use it with some control in my situation I am getting data from sharepoint list and want to show HoverCard for each item description.it will be really helpful for me if I get a more clear example.

Answer (score 0):

@Asad_code,

From the docs, each cell is wrapped with `HoverCard`. In the example, `onRenderItemColumn` will be the "default" item column renderer method. This affects cells within the rows, not the rows themselves.

[image]

Another method is to use `target` property: target element to tag hover card on. If not provided and using HoverCard as a wrapper

BR